# Unit Test with Xamarin iOS is completely broken

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do some Unit Test with Xamarin Forms ( 4.8.0.156 ) on iOS and Android. I've created a Blank project and a blank Unit Test Project with Visual Studio for Mac. On Android everything works fine, but on iOS there is no way to start an unit test. Everytime I start to execute a test, iOS return me this error:

```
at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService.LaunchTestAsync (System.String deviceId, System.String deviceAddress) [0x00353] in <d6deb34c8911492ebfea02a0239d2ab8>:0
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchAppLocal (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, System.Boolean clearAppData) [0x001e8] in <d6deb34c8911492ebfea02a0239d2ab8>:0
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSAppLauncher.LaunchApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient httpClient, Xamarin.UITest.TestCloud.TestCloudiOSAppConfiguration testCloudAppConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient testCloudWsClient, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Http.HttpClient xtcServicesClient, System.Boolean testCloudUseDeviceAgent) [0x00068] in <d6deb34c8911492ebfea02a0239d2ab8>:0
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration, Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Execution.IExecutor executor) [0x0026f] in <d6deb34c8911492ebfea02a0239d2ab8>:0
  at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp..ctor (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.IiOSAppConfiguration appConfiguration) [0x00000] in <d6deb34c8911492ebfea02a0239d2ab8>:0
  at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.iOSAppConfigurator.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode appDataMode) [0x00017] in <d6deb34c8911492ebfea02a0239d2ab8>:0
  at sltdd.UITests.AppInitializer.StartApp (Xamarin.UITest.Platform platform) [0x00018] in /Users/micheleaddante/Project/Mobile/sltdd/sltdd.UITests/AppInitializer.cs:12
  at sltdd.UITests.Tests.BeforeEachTest () [0x00001] in /Users/micheleaddante/Project/Mobile/sltdd/sltdd.UITests/Tests.cs:21
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2020-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs:395
```

I'm using:

- Xamarin forms: 4.8.0.156
- Xamarin.UITest: 307
- Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent 0.21.9

I'm doing the exactly configuration taken from the documentation:

```
return ConfigureApp
.iOS
.InstalledApp("my "bundle name)
.DeviceIdentifier("iPhone simulator id") 
.StartApp();
```

and I'm calling Xamarin.Calabash.Start(); into the method FinishedLaunching of AppDelegate.cs as the documentation says. But there is no way to run a single test. Even an empty test.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using AppCenter? If so, consider ask for AppCenter support in it's portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look to this GitHub Issue

https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/1992#issuecomment-724843179

It seems to be a fail with Xamarin.UITest and XCode 12